# Converting a multi-dimensional object with another object inside into json

Tags: php, json

I have an object I need to convert to json for interacting with an API so I have to maintain objects and array  structure. Take the following:

```
stdClass Object
(
[method] => something
[params] => Array
    (
        [instructions] => stdClass Object
            (
                [a] => 1
                [b] => 2
            )
    )
)
```

Pass it to `json_encode()` but the second object `instructions` gets lost and merely turns it into another array:

```
{ "method":"something",
  "params":{
    "instructions": { "a":1,"b":2 } 
  }
}
```

When I should end up with square brackets around instructions like:

```
{ "method":"something",
  "params":{ 
    "instructions": [ { "a":1,"b":2 } ] 
  } 
}
```

I noticed there is a predefined constant like JSON_FORCE_OBJECT but adding that as an option with json_encode seemed to have 0 effect. What am I missing?

Comment: json_encode is doing it properly. instructions is an object, not an array so why should it come out as an array?

Comment: Exactly. But I didn't know that I wasn't structuring my php object properly. Which is why I said what my output was supposed to end up like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement for `instructions` is to be an array of objects (`[ { } ]` expression that you used), but you set it to be only an object with two fields. Try the following:

```
$arr = (object)[
    'method' => 'something',
    'params' => [
        'instructions' => [
            [
                'a' => 1,
                'b' => 2
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Output:

```
{
    "method": "something",
    "params": {
        "instructions": [
            {
                "a": 1,
                "b": 2
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: BOOM! I see. Learned something new today then about structuring the object in php. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, json_encode works just fine:

```
$x = (object) [
  "method" => "something",
    "params" => [
      "instructions" => (object) [
        "a" => 1,
        "b" => 2
     ]
   ]
];

echo json_encode($x);

// {"method":"something","params":{"instructions":{"a":1,"b":2}}}
```

And this is not valid JSON

```
"instructions": [ "a":1,"b":2 ]
```

there is no such thing as associative array in javascript

---

according to your comment and edit you want to change array to

```
$x = (object) [
  "method" => "something",
    "params" => [
      "instructions" => [
        (object) [
          "a" => 1,
          "b" => 2
       ]
     ]
   ]
];
```

Comment: Yes, correct that isn't valid JSON - I missed a pair of brackets and updated the question. I still need `instructions: [ { "a":1 } ]`

Comment: How should my object in php be structured so that it encodes the object into a list for json?